# Amazon MWS API : How to get Amazon Product status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, amazon-product-api

Currently, I'm using the `GetMatchingProduct` API for getting product related information. It works perfectly.

For now, I have used below mentioned API

`GetMatchingProduct` -

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/products/Products_GetMatchingProduct.html

`GetMatchingProductForId`   -

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/products/Products_GetMatchingProductForId.html

I want to know is there any MWS API available so that I can get the current status of the product of my seller center.

[image]

Comment: Please specify what you are referring to by "current status".

Comment: @CosmoHarrigan - I added image in question

Answer (score 0):

To obtain details on your listings, you should use the [RequestReport](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_RequestReport.html) operation from the [Amazon MWS Reports API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/index.html) and set **ReportType** to one of the [Inventory Reports](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__ListingsReports).

Comment: let me check in detail I guess I have to build another API